# RadioButtonList SelectedIndexChanged not firing everytime

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a RadioButtonList control in asp.net UserControl. It has 2 Radio buttons "Leave" and "Available". On click of Leave, I display alert from SelectedIndexChanged event as "Are you sure you want to take Leave?" with Ok and Cancel buttons. On click of Cancel, it will automatically select "Available". Upto this it is fine.

Step 1: User Clicks Cancel restores to "Available"

Step 2: When User again clicks "Leave", it will not display alert from SelectedIndexChanged of RadioButton.

Step 3: Now it will work again.

For this I have enabled EnableViewState="true" for that UserControl. But still it does not work for the 2nd time.

Below is the Server side SelectedIndexChanged event

```
protected void rdlUser_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rdlUser.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        txtUser.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        radWindowManager.RadConfirm("Are you sure you want to take Leave?", "confirmSave" + this.ClientID, 300, 100, null, "");
    }
}
```

This is the javascript code

```
function confirmSave<%=this.ClientID%>(arg) {
    if (arg == true) {

        $find('<%= FindControl("txtUser").ClientID %>').set_value("");

    }
    else {
        var rdlUser = document.getElementById("<%= rdlUser.ClientID %>");
        var radioButtons = rdlUser.getElementsByTagName('input');
        radioButtons[3].checked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: For Step 2, if you default the selection back to Leave option, then  SelectedIndexChanged event will not fired when you click this option again. The event only fires when the selected option is different from your previous selection. Is there any particular reason you don't use client-side approach?

Comment: I am using telerik RadConfirm here. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code and let me know the result

```
function confirmSave<%=this.ClientID%>(arg) {
    if (arg == true) {
        $find('<%= FindControl("txtUser").ClientID %>').set_value("");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        var rdlUser = document.getElementById("<%= rdlUser.ClientID %>");
        var radioButtons = rdlUser.getElementsByTagName('input');
        radioButtons[3].checked = true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: radWindowManager.RadConfirm("Are you sure you want to take Leave?", "return confirmSave" + this.ClientID +";", 300, 100, null, "");
    }

Comment: This does not work for me @Kiran. Now I am not getting the confirmation message box.

Comment: Can you use `<button onclick="radconfirm('Are you sure?', confirmCallBackFn); return false;">
    show radconfirm</button>` if it can be done only on client side

Comment: <button onclick="radconfirm('Are you sure?', return confirmCallBackFn);"> show radconfirm</button> if it can be done only on client side